# Powershell script problem (Get-content vs assigning to variable)

Tags: powershell, scripting, twitter

I'm attempting to write a Twitter Powershell script that will use community created interfaces [PoshTwitter](http://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/default.aspx/iControl/PsTwitterApi.html) with the Twitter API to attempt and find a list of followers who are potential spammers.

I have a feeling that my problem lies not with the particular cmdlet I'm calling (Get-TwitterFollowers), but rather with the difference between assigning a variable:

If I try this:

```
$rawFol = get-twitterfollowers -page $page -raw 1
```

$rawFol is different than if I do this:

```
get-twitterfollowers -page $page -raw 1 > .\page$page.txt
$rawFol = gc .\page$page.txt
```

The Get-TwitterFollowers cmdlet returns an XML file converted to string.

What things can I try to determine the differences between these two assignments? They look like they'd result with same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is how powershell handles new lines in strings.  When calling the get-twitterfollowers CmdLet, it is either returning a single string or an array of strings.  My guess by your description is that it returns a string.  So the $rawFol variable will have a single string value.  Any new lines are simply embedded into the string value.

The second command you write the return to a file.  Now all of the newlines in the string are represented as lines in the file.  Later when you call gc on that file, each line will be returned as a separate string.  So the $rawFol variable will now have an array of strings.